# how to prevent a logged in user from going to the login page using antdesign umijs dvajs

Tags: reactjs, ant-design-pro, umijs, dvajs

I am working on a project using template antdesign pro with umij and dvajs, I will want to know what to do after storing the token in localstorage if I am logged in not to be redirected to the login page

Comment: Could you please show some of your code samples?

Comment: Provide sample code man !